# how to make a text in one line in php

Tags: javascript

in my js code
it must be one line but when add any text from the db its make it two lines and not work
like

```
function(varone,asdasdasd
adasd);
```

i want it

```
function(varone,asdasdasdadasd);
```

how i can make that by the php any smarty
i useed {strip} and {ldelim} and not worked too
i used tirm not worked too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
$data = str_replace("\r\n", "", $data);
```

If this is HTML, try the function [nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Comment: To specify multiple needles you will need to use an array. So: `str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), "", $data);`

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how would address this in Smarty alone (you could use `{literal}` tags), might be best to remove the new lines in the logic and reassign the variable to your view.

The following will remove multiple spaces and new lines.

```
preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your tag says Javascript, so I assume you don't want a PHP solution.

```
var text = "aaaaaaa
aaaaaaa"

text = text.replace("\r\n","");
```

Newline characters are `\r\n` in Windows or you can try `\n` by itself.  Your string has some of these in it so it's breaking onto a new line.  Just get rid of them and you should be fine.

This will do that operation once; to do it many times use

```
while(text.indexOf("\r\n") != -1) {
  text = text.replace("\r\n","");
}
```